# Magento 2: Cannt do overriding addtocart.phtml for Configurable Products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

It doesn’t work to do an override addtocart.phtml file for configurable products, for single products it works well.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Module_AddCart::css/disableaddtocart.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Module_AddCart::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I dont know where to add this

Comment: **<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this -

First clear your `var/cache` folder using command

`rm -rf var/cache/*`.

Now check template path using path hint for both type products.

In default magento `addtocart` button is rendered from template file for both `simple` and `configurable` products

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

You need to check `catalog_product_view.xml` layout file where template file is defined for both type of products.

In this xml, this code is used for `simple` products-

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

and this code is used for `configurable` products template file --

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

as you can see for both type of products same file `addtocart.phtml` is being used.

So check this xml file for your theme, might be different template file are set there for both type of products

Comment: ok, where i should add this in my file <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

Comment: Replace the body tag by :
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"> Module_AddCart::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"> Module_AddCart::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>